# Condition checking inFor loop

Tags: c

In the for loop the second part i.e, after the 1st semicolon we do the condition checking( say i less than n). If we remove the condition part in general it goes into an infinite loop but here it shows a run time error and also if we simply write exp[] without the index i it gives a compiler error so what is exp[i] here and how is the condition checking taking place?

```
int infixToPostfix(char* exp)
{
int i,k;
for (i = 0, k = -1; exp[i]; ++i)
....
....
}
int main()
{
char exp[] = "a+b*(c^d-e)^(f+g*h)-i";
infixToPostfix(exp);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering no access violation, `exp` is a `char` pointer, `exp[i]` is the value of the `i+i`th `char` element.

Next, the *value* of `exp[i]` is used for condition checking. i.e, `0` for *false*, `non-zero` for *true*.

Comment: So exp[i] evaluates to either 0 or non-zero. By that do you mean a, + and all the operators and operands are non-zero therefore it runs. In main we pass exp to infixToPostfix and the '\o' char is appended to it when we pass by value is that the reason why it terminates when it reaches the end?

Comment: @stack right. The null terminator ascii value is 0.

Comment: So basically we compare the ascii values of all the characters or since they are chars we don't convert them into ascii, we do it only for \0 ? By that i mean to say if i pass an integer say a+b*2 or something else then 2 will be converted into ascii and then the condition will be checked?

Comment: @stack no, in case of char array or string, corresponding ascii values are stored. Integer is a different data type altogether.  Don't mix them up.